# how to write a generalized function to execute sql queries in php?

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net

I am new in Php and mostly I did projects on vb.net and now I want to try something on php, my question is how write a function that accept an string and execute sql queries like, delete and update and insert , like the example below which I did it on vb.net

```
 Public Function ExecuteSQLQuery(ByVal SQLInsertString As String) As Boolean
    Dim err As Boolean = True
    Dim SqlConn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim Sqlcmmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Try
        SqlConn.ConnectionString = ConnectionStrinG
        SqlConn.Open()
        Sqlcmmd.Connection = SqlConn
        Sqlcmmd.CommandText = SQLInsertString
        Sqlcmmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Sqlcmmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        err = False
    Finally
        SqlConn.Close()
        SqlConn.Dispose()
        Sqlcmmd.Connection = Nothing
    End Try
    Return err
End Function
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to open a new connection for every query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used a generic class for this. here are the functions i used. You need to supply the parameters for the conenctions. Example:

```
function OpenLink()
 { // Method : begin
  $this->link = @mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password) or die (print "Class Database: Error while connecting to DB (link)");

 } // Method : end

 function SelectDB()
 { // Method : begin

 @mysql_select_db($this->database,$this->link) or die (print "Class Database: Error while selecting DB");


 } // Method : end

 function CloseDB()
 { // Method : begin
 mysql_close();
 } // Method : end

 function Query($query)
 { // Method : begin
 $this->OpenLink();
 $this->SelectDB();
 $this->query = $query;

 $this->result = mysql_query($query,$this->link) ;//or die (print "Class Database: Error while executing Query");

// $rows=mysql_affected_rows();

if(ereg("SELECT",$query))
{
 $this->rows = mysql_num_rows($this->result);
}

 $this->CloseDB();
 } // Method : end
```

This functions is also for select. you can pass any SQL text. You can choose how to use it, where to open the connections. I open an close in the query function. but you can change that if needed.